# How do I add string given by user inside an empty array and find length of it in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I am new to C++ and was trying a lot to take strings from the user and add those inside an empty array. I read my book but did not get proper explanation. I understand my code is not right but what I am trying to do is, asking a user to give a string, and until the user types "Quit", the program should take the strings and add that to my empty array named listt. After that I declared variable named len and tried to get the length of the array that I just made.
However I am getting several errors and looked for resources to fix my problems. Still I could not do it. It will be genuinely helpful if someone can please help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string listt[];

    string word;
    cout<< "Enter word: ";

    while (word != "Quit" ){

        cin >> word;
        listt.push_back(word);
    }
    cout << listt;

    int len ;

    len = listt.size();
    cout << len;
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++){
        cout << i;
        cout << endl;
    
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You're clearly used to another language, and are incorrectly assuming that code constructs/syntax in that language will work the same way in C++.    That approach almost never works for any combination of language you know and language you wish to learn.   Focus on learning C++, rather than on programming in the language you know.

Comment: Do not use another programming language as a model in writing C++ code.  Even if you did get the code to compile, writing code using another language as a model will either create buggy programs, inefficient programs, or programs that just look plain weird to a C++ programmer.  Also, you shouldn't just be "looking around for resources" when it comes to C++.  The best resources are actual good C++ books.  C++ is a very difficult language to learn properly, and you can't learn it by having a few cheat sheets of instructions here and there, like some other languages.

Comment: What are the error messages You are unable to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You should use vector instead of array:

So instead of:

```
string listt[]; // shouldn't compile anyway
```

use:

```
vector<string> listt;
```

Also, this is not ok:

```
cout << listt; // you can't print array or vector directly, so loop and print each item
```

Also, use for-each instead of C-style for

```
for (const auto &v : listt)
{
    cout << v << endl;
}
```

The rest of your code should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use methods for class vector. You need to include library vector in your programm. Also you need to declare vector of strings as:

```
vector<string>listt;
```

If you want to output each element of the vector you need to use for loop instead.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < listt.size(); i++ ) cout << listt[i] << '\n';
```

So it's not correct

```
cout << listt;
```

Your programm will look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> listt;

    string word;
    cout << "Enter word: ";

    while (word != "Quit") {

        cin >> word;
        listt.push_back(word);
    }

    int len;
    len = listt.size();
    cout << len;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cout << listt[i];
        cout << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `vector<string>`. What you are tried to make is an array, which does not have anything like `push_back()`.

[Vector docs](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)